# How to edit colors of the legend toggle of react google chart if they are activated and desactivated

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 lines graphed, and when I hide one, the color of the bottom line changes to the color of the top one, how do I keep the color the same regardless of the hidden line?

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to find a way to achieve what you wanted and I'm giving you live demo ([React Google Charts - Toggle Line Visibility](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-legend-toggle-line-visibility-stackoverflow-answer-d9drj?file=/index.js)) so you can inspect it and see if that's what you wanted.

It's a little  bit hacky, but hey it's working fine, I guess.

What I did is:

1. Listen for `select` event and detect when `legend` is pressed
2. Apply `series` with some configuration and make it `state` variable for our custom Graph component
3. By setting `lineWidth: 0` and `tooltip: false` we fake line invisibility. Line width trick is obvious... Tooltip is disabled so you can't get tooltip when you try to hover over "invisibile" line on the graph (try to comment out line of code which sets `tooltip: false` and go hover over the area where dot of an "invisible" line is suppose to be to see what I mean by that)

I hope this helps, because there  is nothing out there for this scenario in React.